# Passport-Twitter callback not being triggered?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-twitter

Okay so I am looking to have the service log in with twitter and everything is working until it goes to the callback url and then what it does is it says 'this webpage isnt available' etc etc, no errors in console. If there is any known solutions to this or a way to get a error to appear for debugging it would be appreciated, thanks.

I have gone as far as downloading pre-made apps and it has the same problem so it must be something on my end.

```
const app = express();
// middleware stuff (app.use)
.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' }))
.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}))
.use(bodyParser.json())
.use(passport.initialize())
.use(passport.session());

// Passport Strategy
passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
    consumerKey: twitterconsumerkey,
    consumerSecret: twitterconsumersecret,
    callbackURL: "https://www.example.com/auth/twitter/callback"
  },
  function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {

  }
));

passport.serializeUser((user, cb) => done(null, user));
passport.deserializeUser((obj, cb) => done(null, obj));

// callback and login
app.get('/auth/twitter', passport.authenticate('twitter'));

app.get('/auth/twitter/callback', passport.authenticate('twitter', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
  function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    console.log('hit homepage')
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

These are the twitter api callback urls

```
https://www.example.com/auth/twitter/callback
```

It should redirect to homepage and output 'hit homepage' into the console but it does not happen.

Comment: Where are you hosting your server? At 'https://www.example.com'?. If you are using a local server then use 'http://localhost:port' as callback url. You also have to set the same at Twitter dev portal

Comment: no i am using my own website i just switched it to example.com as i said it is all set up at the api

Comment: The problem is that when it goes to the callback it never reaches it. It says connection lost and nothing is even logged in the console that the page was even attempted to be reached

Comment: have already tried on localhost and main site both encounter same issue'